# How to scroll to the center of UICollectionView (Both Horizontally and Vertically)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I've implemented a collectionview that scrolls both horizontally and vertically (basically its a grid). I want to achieve being able to scroll to an item when it is selected with animation both vertically and horizontally.

Currently I'm using this as a "workaround" but it still jumps for obvious reasons.

```
 self.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredVertically, animated: false)
 self.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
```

Is there anyway to achieve what I want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UICollectionView.ScrollPosition` is an `OptionSet`.

Did you try

```
scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: [.centeredVertically, .centeredHorizontally], animated: false)
```

?

Comment: Thank you! Yes this is what I needed.